# iPhone SDK: How to Kill my app?

Tags: ios4

I've been trying to create a proper Restart feature within my app, which doesn't work (Orientation is meshing up badly) so since this is a prototype I figure it will be easier if I just crash my app and the user taps again the icon.

Is there a way I could kill my application from code within 1-2 sec.?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want to quit your app when user taps on home button instead of going the app into background? If yes you can quit the app when user presses home button by adding a key into your info.plist file application does not run in background and set it's value to true. Here is the original key name UIKeySuspendOnExit I don't remember excatly but it should be like this. Find on google you will get easily.